# How to auto generate multiple temp tables based on an iterated list of existing tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to programmatically retrieve multiple tables  and create a new corresponding temp table containing all data past a certain date for each one. Overall this is to correct a partition problem in SQL Server where the tables use Clustered Column storage.

Below is a code block where I am trying to automate the process by attempting to select from a table into a temporary table. However, the table I am selecting into and from are both variables that are generated by iterating through another temp table not pictured below. I am getting an error in this spot specifically:

[--Select * into @temp_t from @full_table --](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pefl0.png)

I'm not sure that you can select into a table based on the input being a variable. I know I could put ''insert into temp.table''' before the select statement, but then that would mean manually creating a temp version of every table I have to execute this script for. That's a lot of tables. So I'm open to suggestions for doing this differently, but can you

A. tell me if I can select into and from a table that is being defined by variables or

B. is there a automated way of creating an empty version of a table and then selecting the needed data into it?

"@row" was set earlier in the script

```
DECLARE @rowcount2 int = (select count(*) from #partition_3)
set @row =1
while @row <=3  --@rowcount2
Begin
   Declare
   @db_name nvarchar(50), 
   @schema_name nvarchar(50),
   @table_name nvarchar(50), 
   @lower_boundary datetime, 
   @COLUMN_NAME nvarchar(50),
   @temp_t nvarchar(50),
   @full_table nvarchar(50)

   set @db_name = (select DatabaseName from #partition_3 where rowkey = @row)
   set @schema_name  = (select SchemaName from #partition_3 where rowkey = @row)
   set @table_name  = (select TableName from #partition_3 where rowkey = @row)
   set @lower_boundary  = (SELECT LowerBoundary from #partition_3 where rowkey = @row)
   set @COLUMN_NAME  = (Select column_name from #partition_3 where rowkey = @row)
   set @temp_t  = @db_name +'.'+'temp'+'.'+ @table_name
   set @full_table = @db_name+'.'+@schema_name+'.'+@table_name
   
   Select * into @temp_t from @full_table where @COLUMN_NAME >=DATEADD(MONTH, -3,@lower_boundary)
   print @table_name
   set @row = @row+1
end
```

Comment: SQL doesn't allow variables like that, you need dynamic SQL.  And with dynamic SQL you have to deal with temp table scope which is going to be tricky.

Comment: ok, do you have a short example of something that might work or do I just google dynamic Sql?

Comment: It's a whole topic in itself, you'll need to do some research

Comment: You know you can `select Colums into #TempTable from OtherTable` right? Which will automatically create a new temp table.